# Fixed First 3 rows in a table

Tags: jquery, css-position, html-table, fixed

Im having some problems with this.

I'm trying to set up the first 3 columns (letters) in the table to be fixed position when the rest scroll down (numbers).

/*---

JSFiddle with this table:  http://jsfiddle.net/japeljoff/mVVN8/1/

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">F</td>
    <td colspan="2">G</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="1">H</td>
    <td colspan="4">I</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

*/---

any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: I'd tried to asign fixed position to each one of the cells i want to be fixed And I tried to create a div and put it on top of the first three rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes a bit of work and some jQuery, but you can do it by attaching to the scroll event of the window object. You have to mark those header rows as header rows (to make it easier for coding). Make sure to wrap your header rows in `<thead></thead>` and give the `<table>` itself an ID, in this example, "mytable".

You have to add some CSS:

```
.fixedTop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

And JavaScript:

```
var $rt = $("#mytable thead");

var TableTop = $rt.offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > TableTop) {
        $rt.addClass("fixedTop");
    } else {
        $rt.removeClass("fixedTop");
    }
});

//Set widths of the header columns
$("#mytable thead td, #mytable tbody td").width(function (i, width) {
    return $(this).width();
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mVVN8/2/

Comment: This work almost perfect! The new fixed headers move just 1 pixel to the left, that bothers me quite a bit (im a graphic designer). Is it possible to avoid this?

Comment: I'm sure you can just tweak the CSS on the .fixedTop class to nudge it to the left. You might have to play with it a little bit to get it to line up perfectly in all browsers.